# Magento2: Config value cached

Tags: magento2, cache, scope

when i do

```
 return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue("config/user/email", \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Gets the value of the cache and is not correct. How can I make it skip the cache?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the default caching mechanism? Does it work after you refresh the cache?

Comment: Because i change the value but i obtain the old

Comment: You shouldn't have to clear the cache every time - that will be very slow. If you are changing the configuration value so often that you have to clear the cache every time, you should probably be using another form of storage. After updating the configuration (which should be infrequently), running `$ bin/magento cache:clean` should update the configuration cache. Or you can do it in the Admin Cache Management area as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inject the following  dependency into your constructor

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface
 */
protected $cacheTypeList;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
) {
    $this->cacheTypeList = $cacheTypeList;
}
```

and then try to add before you return your new config value the following lines

`$this->cacheTypeList->cleanType(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config::TYPE_IDENTIFIER);
$this->cacheTypeList->cleanType(\Magento\PageCache\Model\Cache\Type::TYPE_IDENTIFIER);`

Comment: It is very slow performing these actions, right? Or is it because I'm in localhost?

Comment: The cache is there to speed up getting config values - if you rebuild the entire config cache each time (instead of using the cache), it will be very slow.

Comment: No, is only for render a form login that depends the config value, i think that the clean of cache will be one time or less for month